# Multiple problems in this code - Type: Missmatch

Tags: java

So I have written a JAVA code that is supposed to tell the user what color he will get if combining two other (from a list) random selected colors. Mind you I am very new to JAVA (have only programmed in Python before).

Code:

```
    package ListOfWords;

     public class testListWords {
  public static void main (String[] args) {

      String [] colors = {"red","green","gray","black","blue","yellow"};

      int colorsLength = colors.length;

      int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);
      int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);

      while(rand1==rand2){
          int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);
      }

      String phrase1 = colors[rand1];
      String phrase2 = colors[rand2];       

      while(phrase1 = "green"){

       if (phrase2 = "red") {
          System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Brown");
        }
       if (phrase2 = "gray") {
          System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Dark Green");
        }
       if (phrase2 = "black") {
          System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Black");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "blue") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Brown");
        }

        if (phrase2 = "yellow") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Brown");
        }
        }
    while(phrase1 = "red"){

        if (phrase2 = "green") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Brown");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "gray") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Dark Red");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "black") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Black");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "blue") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Brown");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "yellow") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Brown");
        }
     }
     while(phrase1 = "gray"){

        if (phrase2 = "red") {
        System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Dark red");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "green") {
        System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Dark Green");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "black") {
        System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Black");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "blue") {
        System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the Dark blue");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "yellow") {
        System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Green");
        }
     }
     while(phrase1 = "black"){

        if (phrase2 = "red") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Black");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "green") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Black");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "gray") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Black");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "blue") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the Black");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "yellow") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Black");
        }
     }
     while(phrase1 = "yellow"){

        if (phrase2 = "red") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Brown");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "green") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Blue");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "gray") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Green");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "blue") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the Green");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "black") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Black");
        }
     }
     while(phrase1 = "Blue"){

        if (phrase2 = "red") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Brown");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "green") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Brown");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "gray") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the Dark blue");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "yellow") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the Green");
        }
        if (phrase2 = "black") {
            System.out.print("Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " " + phrase2 + " " + "will give you the color Black");
        }
    }
}
```

}

So im getting an error message saying:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Duplicate local variable rand2
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Boolean.
```

And im not sure how to fix this - any help please.

Comment: Even in Python, `= != ==`.

Comment: I highly recommend to create a two-dimensional `String[n][3]` array for color1-color2-result records to automatize stuff.

Comment: BLaZuRE - well im sure you are a great programmer - but Im not since I just started - so im learning from my mistakes - but thank you for you helpful comments.

Comment: @Snarre That's fair enough. But personally I suggest just not overthinking things so much. Oft times simpler solutions just work better.

Comment: SharkofMirkwood - thank you

Comment: @Brian Roach -  I don't understand why this question is on hold. I asked a question based on the code I had written and I got a lot of constructive feedback which I took to my heart and learned a lot from. Now my code works and I have learned several new things about JAVA - I thought that was the point of asking questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.  There are a number of problems with what you have written here.  I will try to help you address some of them.

First off, as bas pointed out, in general, if you want to compare two values to see if they are equal, you use ==, not =.  For example:

```
if ( x == y ) {
  //DO STUFF
}
```

Second, bas also pointed this out, in Java you can't use == to compare strings.  What you need to do is:

```
if ( string1.equals(string2) ) {
  //DO STUFF
}
```

Third.  "While".  This one is going to cause lots of issues for you.  While means to keep doing the code that follows, until its test is false.  So, when you do this:

```
while ( myString.equals( "bananas" ) ) {
  System.out.println ( "Lots of bananas." );
}
```

If the string is "bananas", then you'll get this:

```
Lots of bananas.
Lots of bananas.
Lots of bananas.
Lots of bananas.
Lots of bananas.
Lots of bananas.
Lots of bananas.
Lots of bananas.
....
```

Forever.  What you actually want to use is another if.  Actually, there is a convenient piece of logic here as well.  Instead of a bunch of if's, you can modify the statement to use else ifs, since all of these options are mutually exclusive:

```
if ( string1.equals("yellow")) {
  if ( string2.equals("green")) {
    System.out.println("stuff");
  }
  else if ( string2.equals("blue")) {
    System.out.println("more stuff");
  }
}
else if ( string1.equals("green")) {
  if ( string2.equals("blue")) {
    System.out.println("lalala");
  }
  else if ( string2.equals("yellow")) {
    System.out.println("more stuff");
  }
}
```

There are also some much better ways of writing this program that involve a lot less code duplication and ultimately simpler logic, but to avoid overloading you, this is probably sufficient for now.

Comment: TASagent - thank you, I tried to use elif (python) but obviously it didn't work and I didn't know if JAVA had an equivalent - so thank you very much

Comment: No problem.  You can also make your string composition simpler by smashing together your sequential literals.  Instead of "Combining" + " " + phrase1 + " " + "with" + " ", you can use "Combining " + phrase1 + " with ".  The string doesn't care which characters are letters and which are spaces.  It treats them all the same.

Comment: alright, cool thanks again! sorry for the messy code :)

Comment: Everyone starts off with messy code.  You're asking questions, so you're going in the right direction.  The next step for improvement will be to use a 2-D array to hold the outcome of combining the two colors.  The array will be something like mixedColors[rand1][rand2], then you can print with one line.  Enums can also be used to make the assignment of the mixedColors array and the 1-D color array less arbitrary and more robust to future changes.  Also faster, because then you can compare the random number instead of the strings (because its slower to do string compares), but that's up to you.

Comment: Im still struggling with the random selection of colors, I removed the duplicate of rand2 and only use: int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength-1);.... but the fact that it sometimes will pick the same colors(or index number) remain.

Comment: What you had above will *almost* work.  You just need to change "int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength)" to "rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength)".  ie, delete the extra 'int' declaration.  What you're doing right now is declaring a NEW variable with the same name that just lives inside the scope of that while statement.  I don't know to what extent your compiler will complain.  Deleting the int will make rand2 actually use the value from 'above', which is what you want.  Kajacx also made an alternative recommendation below.

Comment: Yes I got it to work now - its still a lot of lines of code but the code works fine. Now Im going to learn 2-D arrays - thank you so much! - you have been most helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly `=` is for assignment, you must use `==` as a boolean operator.

Secondly, to compare strings in Java you need to call the `equals()` method on a string.

```
if ("red".equals(phrase2)) {
    // logic here
}
```

Thirdly you assign rand2 two times. You must either use another variable for the second time or you must remove the `int` indication.

```
int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);

while(rand1==rand2){
    rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is this:

```
while(rand1==rand2){
    int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);
}
```

You've already declared `rand2`, so don't do that again. You should change it to:

```
while(rand1==rand2){
    rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);
}
```

Another thing is, you're mixing the assignment operator (`=`) with the equality operator (`==`). The former assigns a value to a variable, and the latter checks if variables are equal.

When you're trying to match variables, use `==`.

Lastly, in Java, you can't use the equality operator to check strings - this will literally match one object to another and see if they are the same object. You have to use the `equals` method instead, like this:

```
while(phrase1.equals("green"))
```

Instead of this:

```
while(phrase1 = "green")
```

Or even `while(phrase1 == "green")` (which would work for integers/booleans/other types).

Answer (score 0):

For comparing strings in Java you will have to use equals() method use `"red".equals(phrase2)` or `"red".equalsIgnoreCase(phrase2)`

`==` operator in Java is used for checking equality and `=` is an assignment operator. But Strings in Java are Objects of `String.class` so == does **reference check** rather than value check.

So to compare two objects in Java you use `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

one syntax error here:

```
  int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);
  int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);

  while(rand1==rand2){
      //int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength); - wrong
      //rand2 is already defined, you can write only
      rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);
  }
```

also, if you want 2 different random numbers, you can:

```
  int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * colorsLength);
  int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * (colorsLength-1));
  if(rand2 >= rand1) rand2++;
```